# android system drawable ic_btn_round_more

Tags: android, system, drawable

is there some way how to access android system private drawable: ic_btn_round_more?
   This is the more icon which is used
   in DialogPreference (res.layout.preference_dialog.xml)
   It's not accessible through android.R.drawable

I don't want to copy bitmap file, because
   that icon can be different for every device.
   I found this: http://www.androidjavadoc.com/2.3/android/R.attr.html#moreIcon  But I'm not sure how can I use it. Basically I'm trying to add more icon to my custom ListView,
 which whould look exactly android way.

Comment: You probably know that you can access all the `more button` images on `C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-12\data\res` Now coping them to corresponding directoryes (drawable-mdpi, drawable-ldpi, drawable-hdpi) and using them from there depending on the devices dpi/screen size? (don't know if this helps)

Comment: problem is that there is different more icon for HTC and Samsung galaxy, that's reason I want to avoid copying resources

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nine-patch to create your own rounded button which can be exactly the same as drawable ic_btn_round_more. you can get more information about how to use Nine-Patch here : http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/draw9patch.html

Comment: I have my own custom Icon in current version, but again I want use some nice android way because that icon is different for HTC and Samsung Galaxy